# How can I install GNOME 3.12 on saucy (13.10)?

Tags: gnome

After reading the following blog post and YouTube video:

- [GNOME 3.12 Debuts With Polish, Improvements Galore | OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/03/whats-new-improved-gnome-3-12)
- [Top 12 Features of GNOME 3.12 | OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/03/top-12-features-gnome-3-12)
- [GNOME 3.12 Released - See What`s New [Video, Screenshots] ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/gnome-312-released-see-whats-new-video.html)
- [Introducing GNOME 3.12 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n77cwRJUrLg)

I would like to try out GNOME 3.12. How do I install it on my saucy(amd64)?

Comment: We traditionally dupe these questions that always appear at a new gnome-release - just wait until the PPA's are updated or follow the instructions in the master question to compile from source.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a live image in gnome's website:

[Getting GNOME | GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/)

**Try the latest release**

GNOME 3.12 is the latest version and will be available in distributions in the future. In the mean time, you can try our live demo image.

---

Instructions for installing the image on to a USB stick with GNU/Linux:

> - Insert the drive (any data it contains will be erased!)
> - Run dmesg in a terminal: this will give you the location of the stick in square brackets, such as sdb
> - To write the image, run sudo dd if=gnome-3.12.iso of=/dev/DRIVE bs=8M conv=fsync, replacing DRIVE with the location (e.g., /dev/sdb but not e.g., /dev/sdb1)
> - Once the write operation has finished, you can reboot with the USB drive inserted (you may have to specify the boot device on startup)

Comment: Awh, no ppa/compiling/deb file?